# Unable to Manually Trigger GitHub Action

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I recently started working on using some GitHub actions on my projects. I am able to setup them up to run automatically but am struggling with having them run manually. I know that you need the have the workflow_dispatch in the on section. I'm not sure if it's not working because I have it automatically run too. Is someone able to tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is one of my workflow YAML files

```
name: Create-Doc-Nightly

on:  
  push:
    branches: [ "nightly" ]
    paths:
      - 'src/**'
      - 'pom.xml'
 
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  doc:
    name: Create Doc
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        name: Step 1 - Checkout Nightly Branch
        with:
          persist-credentials: false
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Step 2 - Setup JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3.4.1
        with: 
          java-version: 17
          distribution: 'temurin'
      - name: Step 3 - Remove Doc
        run: |
          git remote set-url origin https://jnstockley:${{ secrets.TOKEN }}@github.com/jnstockley/BTTN.git
          git config user.email "jack@jstockley.com"
          git config --local user.name "Jack Stockley"
          git rm -r docs
          git commit -m "Removed Docs"
          git push origin nightly
      - name: Step 4 - Create Doc
        run: mvn dokka:dokka -f pom.xml
      - name: Step 5 - Move Docs
        run: |
           rm -rf docs
           mkdir -p docs
           mv target/dokka/* docs
      - name: Step 6 - Publish docs
        run: |
          git remote set-url origin https://jnstockley:${{ secrets.TOKEN }}@github.com/jnstockley/BTTN.git
          git config user.email "jack@jstockley.com"
          git config --local user.name "Jack Stockley"
          git add -f docs
          git commit -m "Updated Docs"
          git push origin nightly
```

Link to GitHub repo, nightly branch: https://github.com/jnstockley/BTTN/tree/nightly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow must be on your default branch in order to use `workflow_dispatch`.

I believe in your case it's only on the branch `nightly` while it should also be on `main`.

Answer (score 1):

To manually trigger a workflow, use the workflow_dispatch event. You can manually trigger a workflow run using the GitHub API, GitHub CLI, or GitHub browser interface. For more information, see [Manually running a workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow)

```bash
on: workflow_dispatch
```

#### Providing inputs

You can configure custom-defined input properties, default input values, and required inputs for the event directly in your workflow. When you trigger the event, you can provide the ref and any inputs. When the workflow runs, you can access the input values in the inputs context. For more information, see [Contexts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts)

This example defines inputs called `logLevel`, `tags`, and `environment`. You pass values for these inputs to the workflow when you run it. This workflow then prints the values to the log, using the `inputs.logLevel`, `inputs.tags`, and `inputs.environment` context properties.

#### yaml

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      logLevel:
        description: 'Log level'
        required: true
        default: 'warning'
        type: choice
        options:
        - info
        - warning
        - debug
      tags:
        description: 'Test scenario tags'
        required: false
        type: boolean
      environment:
        description: 'Environment to run tests against'
        type: environment
        required: true

jobs:
  log-the-inputs:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo "Log level: $LEVEL"
          echo "Tags: $TAGS"
          echo "Environment: $ENVIRONMENT"
        env:
          LEVEL: ${{ inputs.logLevel }}
          TAGS: ${{ inputs.tags }}
          ENVIRONMENT: ${{ inputs.environment }}
```

If you run this workflow from a browser you must enter values for the required inputs manually before the workflow will run.

[image]

You might like the following documentation links

[workflow_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch)

[github docs - events-that-trigger-workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows)